# Validating Textbox with CustomValidator's ClientValidationFunction not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having some serious issues with this. I have a two fields like this, both of them being assigned datepickers with jquery.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RTRP" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator3" 
   ControlToValidate="RTRP"
   Text="No date selected" 
   ValidateEmptyText="True"
   ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate" 
   Display="Static">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="ContEd" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator1"
    ControlToValidate="ContEd"
    Text="No date selected" 
    ValidateEmptyText="True"
    ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate" 
    Display="Static">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

With the following javascript to validate it.

```
$("#<%=RTRP.ClientID %>").datepicker();
$("#<%=ContEd.ClientID %>").datepicker();

function clientValidate(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = args.Value.length > 0;
}
```

Both get their datepickers, but the validation function simply refuses to be fired and always allows the form to submit. I am completely lost here, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if a string's `length` is less than 0 (what is never true) here:

```
function clientValidate(sender, args) {
    if (args.Value.length < 0) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    } else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want(you could simpy use a `RequiredFieldValidator`), but...

```
function clientValidate(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = args.Value.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but it still does not seem to trigger at all. Even tried to call an alert and changing the text in another field, but apparently it is skipping it completely.

Comment: @JesusZamora: Your `TextBoxes` don't have `AutoPostBack="true"`(default is `false)`, maybe you want to postback immediately.

Comment: @JesusZamora: But where's the submit button you use?

Comment: It's within the same asp:Content as both textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign $.datepicker() behaviour to any text, and run page.. you will find that textbox on which you override jQuery datepicker had css set display : none.. so that might be the reason that custom validation not getting for that textbox...

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="id" controltovalidate="controlname" erormessage="please enter the dates"> 
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

correct me i am wrong

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have used, but later on I need it to be able to check if a checkbox is checked in order to proceed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change you method to this.and try again

```
function clientValidate(sender, args)
{
  if(Page_ClientValidate())
  {
   if (args.Value.length < 0)
   {
    args.IsValid = false;
   } else
   {
    args.IsValid = true;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: `clientValidate` is already the event handler, this would cause an infinite loop( imho ).